# Convergence of the sequence of decimals of natural numbers and its subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the sequence $$0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, \ldots$$

Does this sequence converge? Does it have convergent subsequences?  If so, what are their respective limits?

---

My thoughts:  no, it doesn't converge because it always returns to the value 0.1 before increasing again to the next digit along.  But I can see a lot of convergent subsequences like $0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \ldots$, which converges to 1.  I wonder if there is an exhaustive way to identify these subsequences?  And is there a concise way to express them?

Comment: You can get a subsequence that converges to any given real number between $0$ and $1$.  e.g. $\{.1,.14,.141, .1415,.14159,\dots\}\rightarrow \pi-3$

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: @lulu thanks! but surely it's any given real number between 0.1 and 1?  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You are correct.  Your sequence starts at $.1$ and doesn't allow "whole numbers" of the form $007$, say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. So, you are correct. As @lulu pointed out, you can get a subsequence that converges to any decimal.

Can you enumerate them all? No. Here's why:

For any convergent subsequence, you can mix in values from *any* other sequence, provided that you are only mixing in a *finite* number of such values. So you can construct arbitrary converging subsequences.